# Insert and Read from Table ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I've been banging my head all day long. I'm new to MVC 5 (MVC and ASP.NET in general) and I can't figure out how do I add an extra table to my current Database (created using CodeFirst approach), and read its content.

Heck, I don't know how to read the other columns I have in the AspNetUsers Table from Identity.

Would someone kindly tell me how this is done? Thanks a million

**Edit:** 
Ok. So I have been tirelessly looking for a solution, and I've come across 35% of it.

I've stumbled upon a book called "Getting Started with Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 5 with Tom Dykstra"

Now I know that for creating a table you just create a class under the Model folders, and use a DbSet<> command where you had applied the DbContext call.

Now, what's the problem here? I started from a blank template, since that is the suggestion from "Pro ASP.NET MVC 5" from Adamn Freeman, and I don't want Google, Facebook Authentication.

I have been able to populate the defacto AspNetUsers table with custom fields, and insert Data into it.

What I want to with it, is to create a relational table with a foreign key which should reside in the defacto AspNetUsers table, and I don't how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the entity class (new table). You must specify an attribute as the primary key that should be named (CLASSNAME)ID Ex:

   ```
   public class Product
   {
       public int ProductID { get; set; }
       public string PropriedadeTeste { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Map this entity in your implementation of DbContext. This means that **Products** table will contain **Product** objects:

   ```
   public class EFDbContext : DbContext
   {
       public EFDbContext() : base("DatabaseName") { }

       public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. Enable migrations in your project (in the Package Manager Console)

   **`Enable-Migrations -ProjectName SportStore.Domain -ContextTypeName ENTER_NAMESPACE_HERE.EFDbContext`**
4. Generate the migration - in this example, it will be generated a file named something like 201409172255007_Product.cs, in the Migrations folder:

**`Add-Migration -ProjectName PROJECT_NAME Product`**

5. Update the database:

**`Update-Database -ProjectName PROJECT_NAME -TargetMigration Product`**